# How i can hide minicart in header and display when product add to cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, addtocart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I have tried everything to hide the **cart from my website** and display it **when any product added to cart** by clicking on "Add To Cart" button, but it didnt work, i am using magento 2.1, any helps are really appreciated.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: add your cart icon  before counter because counter come hidden default, so remove cart icon from anchor class ".minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before" and add  before counter span in minicart.html file